# Hundreds of thousands of words contained in such a small package

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, steganography

> If you find that you are crafty you will see the answer's: ___________

```
CfAaEuDbLcIuHk
DbBaAbEbAiEfIa
JaCaEaIcIcEfIa
JaCaAaEfAaEfIa
BcJkAaEfAaEfIa
EbIkAuEfAaEfIa
EbIkAbEfAaEfIa
DfAqEaEfAaEfIa
IcEfEaAiAaEfIa
IcGfEaIcIcEfIa
EfDiAbEbAqEfIa
AuCuAuDbLkIuHk
```

**hint**

> The mods might have something to say about how this can be solved.

**hint #2**

> Each pair is a byte-sized portion

Comment: I feel like these are shortened URL links, but goo.gl and bit.ly don't match, so maybe not...

Comment: Everything needed to solve the puzzle is contained within the puzzle it just requires some lateral-thinking... i guess i could add that tag.

Comment: Title probably refers to a book

Comment: Good guess but no...

Comment: Ok, these aren't amazon IDs either :)

Comment: And not chemical elements.

Comment: Yeah they're nothing external.

Comment: The first hint may suggest mod like in modular reduction. Just a guess -- haven't looked :-)

Comment: I checked the [revision history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/63286/revisions) and came up empty. Seemed like a good solution for the mods hint but no

Comment: A few pairs of letters are repeated several times, but I'm not seeing any obvious way to turn the pairs into "bytes" (as in eight binary bits)

Comment: there are few symbols of chemical elements such as Cf ,Eu, Db,Ba, Ca, Au, Cu. Also the mods hint might mean Neutron moderator. Bytes hint is little difficult to apply to this.

Comment: Any new hints for this coming? I think I have a new lead but I'm stuck. :(

Comment: Is answer supposed to be possessive?

Answer (score 1):

> Cornucopia ??
> My answer is based on knitting...
> 'f' for front
> 'b' for back or behind
> 'a' for across or around
> I'm still not 100% sure of this answer

Comment: I'm new to this community :)  But I would like a yes / no confirmation of my answer from the author before I give my technique.  Or are we supposed to collaboratively solve?

Comment: @Kevin The way answers work here is that you provide both the answer *and* your reasoning, and then the author tells you whether you're correct or not (though it's worth noting that in this case, he hasn't logged in since August). You also need to put a spoiler tag `>!` before your answer to hide it, so anyone else who wants to have a go at the puzzle can do so.